# Detail in new tab according date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have 2 tabs

1.`UITableView` with `NSArray`.
2.Detail for today.

And I have `DetailViewController`

On the tab 1 have names of fruit:

- Lemon
- Banana
- Apple
- Strawberry

When you select cell on `UITableView` you go to `DetailViewController`

How I do on the tab 2 will be displayed the fruit according date.

Example:The date for today is 16 August on the tab 2 its display the fruit lemon.
More Example:The date for today is 21 December on the tab 2 its disply the fruit Apple.

(The detail of fruit it's will be taken from `DetailViewController`

How I do it?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do :

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
//uncomment to get the time only
//[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd,MMM,YYYY"];
//[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

//get the date today
NSString *dateToday = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

You may ask for the `dateToday` with `isEqualToString` and then decide what to show or not :)

Comment: I don't understand on NSString I wirte 1 Novmber = Apple ?

And how take is detail from DetailViewController?

Thanks (sorry I am beginner developer)